# Is it possible to run 100+ Services or Intent Services at a time in Android?

Tags: service

Is it possible to run 100+ Services or Intent Services at a time in Android?

I mean, is there any limit to run no of services run in the background?

Any Solutions will be appreciate

Comment: I have to wonder what sort of problem would lead someone to think "the solution here is to create 100 services" - and also not to wonder about how well the android device would work if every developer decided to do that sort of thing.

Comment: I mean, is there any limit to run no of services run in the background?